# Options for showing content based on a member field

Tags: members

I'm about to start building a system where we need to display different content for different users, but all these users will be part of the same usergroup "students". I'm trying to work out the best way to group the various members of this user group together into "schools".

So basically I could end up with 150 students with 50 in school1, 50 in school 2 and 50 in school3.

My initial thinking was that we'd simply have a custom member field named school and then on each template check this field and display articles from a category with the same name as the custom member field, but i'm not 100% sure this is the most effective/scalable way of doing it so am looking for more ideas.

Any other ideas or add-ons/modules that could help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up having a "School code" on the registration process, using member custom fields. I then have a School channel which contains the school name and the code, I then check against this when pulling out articles. Lots of if else's but does the trick!